# How can i create cool gui effects in OpenGL ES 1.1 game?

Tags: android, user-interface, opengl-es

I'm creating a 2d android game with OpenGL ES 1.1 and i'm not using a game engine.I'm using my own framework.

I'm wondering about how people create cool gui's for their game?Are all parts of it is drawing only?

Also how can i create cool transitions between screens?What is the way for it?Maybe any library or method for this?

EDIT:
Look that video,when he touch to credits there is a transition between screens.That's what i mean the transition between screens.

http://youtu.be/JdfgGMBvqTk?t=4m54s

Comment: _I'm using my own framework_ -- don't, better start with a pre-tested library (aka engine). It's easier that way unless you want to sell your framework or have a homework ;)

Comment: I want to learn it and i don't want to pay for a license.

Comment: How did your game engine work out in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a cool GUI, I suggest you get into contact with a graphics designer if your GIMP or PS skills won't suffice. Transitions are a combination of code and graphics. You'll have to play around with it. eg. Transitions are made the same way you would make a game.

Comment: So gui part of a game is like an animation?

Comment: Yes, if you want the GUI to have transitions, then it's like an animation.

Answer (score 0):

When people talk about game "GUI" they usually talk about HUD or game graphics.  HUD is the interface that overlays the game (buttons, menus, counters, etc.); game graphics are the images used to draw the terrain, game characters, weapons, etc. Both are drawn by artists and given to programmers who need to figure out how to put them in the game.  I suggest you follow the advice given by Artur and learn an Open Source game engine.  You will learn how to design your game and you will learn how to program it much faster.  There are dozens of free game engines for Android listed here: http://www.mobilegameengines.com/android